# Get records for a particular hour and an average of corresponding data

Tags: javascript

I call a webservice and get data. The data is in the format -

```
mail: "xyz@xyz.com"
price: "9.5"
name: "xyz"
receiveddate: "1374484561920"
```

I convert the date in millis to date and find the hour in which price was something. So eachEntryDate has the hour i.e 11, 12, 13 etc.

```
for(var l=0; l<data.length; l++){
    var dataDate = recs[l].receiveddate;
    dataDate = +dataDate;
    var eachEntryDate = new Date(+dataDate.toString());
    eachEntryDate = eachEntryDate.toString();
    eachEntryDate = parseInt(eachEntryDate.substr(16, 2));
    hourlyRecs[l] = {hour:eachEntryDate, price:recs[l].price};
}
```

Now i want to get the average of the price for each hour. i.e. the average of the price where the hour is 11,12 etc. The data is in a random order. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you got a database access for this? Or do you have to do everything in JS?

Comment: I have to do everything in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish with this:

```
hourlyRecs.sort(function(a,b) { return a.hour - b.hour; } );

var results = [];
var value = {};
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;
var hour = hourlyRecs[0].hour;

for(var i = 0; i < hourlyRecs.length; i++) {

    if (hourlyRecs[i].hour == hour) {
        sum += hourlyRecs[i].price;
        count++;
    }
    else {
        value.avg = sum / count;
        value.hour = hourlyRecs[i].hour;

        results.push(value);        

        value = {};
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;

        sum += hourlyRecs[i].price;
        count++;
    }
}
value.avg = sum / count;
value.hour = hourlyRecs[i].hour;

results.push(value);
```

You would end up with an array of hour/avgPrice.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Since everything has to be done in JS, let's organize the data first.

Create **2 arrays with 24 elements** - one for **cost at each hour** and **one for counts**. (or just one holding 2 values)

As you loop through the data, **increase** the relevant cost at each time and **bump up** the count.

Something like this:

```
var counts = [];
var costs = [];

for(var i = 0; i < recs.length; i++) {
    // This is your current code
    var dataDate = recs[l].receiveddate;
    dataDate = +dataDate;
    var hour = new Date(+dataDate.toString());
    hour = hour .toString();
    hour = parseInt(hour .substr(16, 2));

    // Extend it with this
    counts[hour]++;
    costs[hour] += recs[l].price;
}
```

And then just divide the cost by count and thee you go. This way you don't have to worry about sorting the data or anything like that.

Also, your **hour picking** function can be **simplified** if you just **divide** the numebr of milliseconds by 3600000 - the number of mills in 1 hour and take the int out of it.

```
hour = parseInt(milliseconds / 3600000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `array` which will hold all the **prices per hour**.

### JavaScript

```js
/* Fill an array by hour, containing all the prices for that hour */
var average = [];
for (var elem in hourlyRecs) {
    average[hourlyRecs[elem].hour].push(hourlyRecs[elem].price);
}

/* get the average per each hour*/
for (var hour in average) {
    var priceAverage = 0;
    var count = 0;
    for (var price in average[hour]) {
        priceAverage += average[hour][price];
        count+=1;
    }
    average[hour]["priceAverage"] = parseFloat(priceAverage/count,10);
}
```

Average for hour #11: `average[11]["priceAverage"]`.